# How can I make a form element behave differently based on radio button selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to web development. I'm creating a new application where in I'm designing a form where the elements differ based on the selection of radiobuttonlist.
For example -
I have a radiobutton list -
Gender and options are Male and Female.

**For Male:**
Next element of the form will be textfield **Extra Curricular activities:** and students can type anything like Judo,Karate,etc.

**For Female:**
Next element of the form will be Dropdown Menu **Extra Curricular activities:** has options Dance, Ballet, etc
Based on the selection of the above radiobuttons the next elements should be displayed and the data entered will be converted into JSON format and stored in Database.

Now, to achieve this I have put the same field as dropdownlist in one div and the textfield in another div. I use jQuery to hide and show div respectively.
I want the same textfield with ID and name to behave differently based on radio button selection in two different scenarios.

Extra Curricular activities is used as textfield for Male children and dropdown for Female children. Ultimately the values from the same element(either textfield or dropdown) should be entered into database.
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3s8wM/1/)
Am I doing the right way.
**Code-**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('#id_radio1').click(function () {
        $('#multi_language').hide('fast');
        $('#single_language').show('fast');
    });
    $('#id_radio2').click(function () {
        $('#single_language').hide('fast');
        $('#multi_language').show('fast');
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input id="id_radio1" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio1" >Single</input> 
    <input id="id_radio2" type="radio" name="name_radio1" value="value_radio2">Multi</input>
    <br />    
    <div id="single_language" style="display:none;">
        <p>One</p>
    </div>
     <div id="multi_language" style="display:none;">
        <p>Two</p>
    </div>


</form>
```

Comment: Please post a fiddle link or your html & script.

Comment: I have posted it. Why so many votes. I'm asking a question

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered such thing before. You can either generate the elements dynamically based on selection of radio button using `append()` or you can initially create them on page load and `detach()/remove()` them based on your needs.

The functions I have named are in jQuery. You can use javascript equivalents of the same.